# SSRS snapshot of a report

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Is it possible to create a report and have it once a month save to a .pdf or an excel automatically and email out to a list of people as a snapshot, can this be done on express edition, if at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Diego says, you are describing [SSRS subscriptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155911%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Data Driven subscriptions are only available with SQL Server Enterprise edition, and Express does not [support any subscriptions:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365166.aspx)

> - All reports are processed on demand. Scheduled or unattended report
>     processing is not supported.

If you need to use Express edition, then you'll need to build your own solution. But that would probably justify the cost of a standard Sql Server license.

Comment: nice, I forgot to talk about the version issue +1

Answer (score 2):

what you want is a subscription (probably a Data-Driven Subscription). 
A subscription can deliver a report at a specific time or in response to an event.

To do that you will need to use  stored credentials or no credentials  (Windows Authentication is not applicable) because the subscription will run as a background process.

A snapshot is one of the 3 ways of running a report (other than "on demand" and "on demand from cache")

Answer (score 0):

I realize it is the poor man's solution, but if you are limited to SSRS Express Edition, you can set up a scheduled job (via cron, SQL Server Agent, Scheduled Tasks, etc.) that simply emails out a URL link to the report with various parameters set (or to a snapshot version if applicable) that people can then click on and go to the Report Manager and view.

In a way, this can actually be an elegant solution when your reports require Windows Authentication to filter datasets (for example, when accessing a SSAS cube-based dataset) and it's not secure to have the report run with a stored credential.